# How in Dart Editor revert back (turn off) an option "Don't Analyze" script?

Tags: user-interface, dart, usability, dart-editor

How in Dart Editor revert back (turn off) an option "Don't Analyze" script?

I turn on this option on a script but I don't know how to turn it off on this script (allow to analyze).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where the `Don't Analyze` context menu item is shown for normal files or folders the menu item `Analyze` is shown for files or folders where `analyze` is deactivated. Use this menu item to enable analyzing.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! File have very long name and extension was not visible in `File` panel. I accidentally renamed it and I did not notice that he does not have the extension "dart". Your answer helped me (where this option available).